# Running two subscribers concurrently in the same node

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, callback, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a problem and need to use the most recent pose from `amcl/future` (my self-designed topic) and publish it as a `tf` between two frames.

I made two subscribers for: `amcl_pose/future` and `clock`. The subscriber for `amcl_pose/future` **updates** a `pose` struct inside my code whenever it receives a new pose estimate from amcl; the subscriber for `clock` ignores the `clock` message and publish the most recent pose from the structure to `tf` (basically use it to publish `tf` in a high rate).

The problem is that **the `amcl_cb` function is never called** by ROS. I believe it might be a concurrency issue because the two callbacks share the same data structure. What is the "correct" way to implement this? My code snippet is provided.

**Note: the pose published is not the amcl estimated pose. **
**The `parent_frame` and `child_frame` are only to simplify the snippet, so it is not related. **

```
void amcl_cb(const geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped::ConstPtr& p){
    pose.header = p->header;
    pose.pose = p->pose;
}

void clock_cb(const rosgraph_msgs::Clock::ConstPtr& dummy){
    tf::TransformBroadcaster broadcaster;
    broadcaster.sendTransform(
    tf::StampedTransform(
    tf::Transform(
      tf::Quaternion(pose.orientation.x, pose.orientation.y, pose.orientation.z, pose.orientation.w), 
      tf::Vector3(pose.position.x, pose.position.y, pose.position.z)),
    ros::Time::now(),"parent_frame", "child_frame"));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "robot_tf_publisher");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber amcl_sub = n.subscribe<geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped>("amcl_pose/future",1000, amcl_cb);
    ros::Subscriber clock_sub = n.subscribe<rosgraph_msgs::Clock>("clock",1000, clock_cb);
    ros::spin();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294802/running-two-subscribers-concurrently-in-the-same-node/) by [alex_f224](https://answers.ros.org/users/35926/alex_f224/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2018-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-06-21**:
This is just a guess, but... `amcl` does, by [Default](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl#Published_Topics), not have a Topic that is called `amcl_pose/future`. Do you remap `amcl_pose` to `amcl_pose/future`?

Additionally, it does not make sense to use the clock to republish this. Either use a `ros::Timer`..

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-06-21**:
.., if you want this published with another, static, frequency, or publish this directly from the `amcl_cb`.
Last but not least, are you sure your frames are called `parent_frame` and `child_frame`?

But I might be missing something important. So maybe elaborate why you chose that approach?

**Comment by [alex_f224](https://answers.ros.org/users/35926/alex_f224/) on 2018-06-21**:
Thanks for asking. No, it is not the amcl pose. In fact, I used the amcl_pose to make some prediction, which publishes a topic I call `amcl_pose/future`.

**Comment by [alex_f224](https://answers.ros.org/users/35926/alex_f224/) on 2018-06-21**:
The `parent_frame` and `child_frame` are only to simplify the snippet, so it is not related.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-21**:\

> I believe it might be a concurrency issue because the two callbacks share the same data structure.

No, that is most likely not the case here. `ros::spin()` implements a single-threaded callback queue, so calls to your two callbacks are serialised.

**Comment by [pengjiawei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31790/pengjiawei/) on 2018-06-21**:
try this
while(n.ok()){

subscriber;

ros::spinOnce();

}

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-21**:
What does `subscriber` do? And what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved. Just to let everyone know.

Firstly, there is no "bug" in the code; it is just that `amcl` does not publish pose unless the robot moved. Therefore, `amcl_cb` was never called.

I changed my code using the `ros::Timer` suggestion by @mig to publish tf.

It works fine at the end.

---

Originally posted by [alex_f224](https://answers.ros.org/users/35926/alex_f224/) with karma: 28 on 2018-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0